# Is it possible to lock an orientation in a PWA?

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, screen-orientation

I wrote a PWA which should be used in portrait mode (this is a home application used by four people). I would like to lock it in portrait mode so that when the screen of the mobile is rotated, the application does not react and stays in portrait mode.

I hoped that the [`orientation` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/orientation) in the manifest would help but it simply sets the default orientation the application starts with.

Is there a **PWA mechanism** that I could use to say "*no matter the orientation, keep the portrait mode*"?

The workaround I will use if the above is not possible is to have a view for the rotated screen, but it will not bring anything else than aesthetics and I would prefer to have my highly-computer-deficient family only see the portrait mode.